# Enviar ArrayList<T> desde android a webservice asp.net

Tags: android, array, webservice, asp, lista

estoy trabajando con un webservice asp que me recibe como parametro un list, en android estoy usando la libreria ksoap2 la cual no soporta enviar este tipo de parametyros sin ser parchada antes. Hay alguna alternativa a esta libreria o alguien sabe como es el metodo para parchar ksoap?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Despues de mucho investigar note que enviar un arraylist con ksoap es muy complicado y me resulto mas facil hacer un JSON el cual converti en un string y recibirlo de esta manera en el webservice.

De esta forma pude enviar 25.000 registros desde android a ASP.NET.

Espero esta info sea de utilidad para alguien más.

Answer (score 1):

[**ksoap2**](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net) no soporta serializar arrays, el "parche" que necesita es :

http://people.unica.it/bart/2010/12/03/ksoap2-patch-for-user-defined-objects-and-arrays/

**

> La versión actual de kSOAP2, la biblioteca de Android para
>   comunicación a través de SOAP, no ofrece instalaciones para serializar
>   y deserializar objetos complejos. Además, las matrices no son
>   compatibles.

**